# How to include CSS in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I am building a Symfony 5 app and want to use CSS inside my twig templates.  My stylesheet is at **public/css/styles.css** and so I try to use it in my twig template with the line `<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`.  This works locally but once I deploy it to the Google Cloud Platform the server can no longer find it.  The console shows a 404 error when trying to find the stylesheet.  Where does Symfony want me to put my css files?

This feels like it should be very simple but I'm totally at a loss and feel like I'm missing something stupid.  The documentation only really talks about Encore and that seems like such overkill for using a single CSS file in a twig template.

Comment: Have you host your website in /public ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the CSS working.  I think what did it was telling `app.yaml` to put the css in the public folder.

```
handlers:
  - url: /css
    static_dir: public/css
```

Then instead of loading using the asset() function, I included the css with:

`<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

That way, the css folder I had in public locally was put in public when deployed to the GCP.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry i cant comment because low reputations, thatswhy i need to take an answer)

At first, the location of your css is correct. Also the usage of your link tag looks fine. Now the question is: what is the correct error message, or better where looks the browser to your file?

I think the browser want to take your file from root, not from public folder. If you can answer this with yes, you have to check your .htaccess file and/or linking from webspace to startfolder (public) in this cause.
It works in localhost because the symfony dev-server take this work for you.